# Writing two Dataframes with different data to a single excel file. Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This might be an odd question but I'm trying to write some data to an excel sheet in order to make a schedule based of data read in from a different sheet.  I currently have it set up so I can write one DataFrame and change the color of the cells based upon the information. Now I would like to add new information into these cells while keeping the color.

```
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
import glob, os
import math

runDir = "/Users/AaronsMac/Documents/"

if os.getcwd() != runDir:
    os.chdir(runDir)

files = glob.glob("edcLineup_*.xlsx")
schedule = glob.glob("edcSetTime*.xlsx")
print schedule


for each in files:
    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names
    sheets = sorted(sheets)
    df = {}
    for sheet in sheets:
        df = pd.read_excel(each, sheet, index_col='Artists')


#print df

colNames = list(df.columns.values)
artists = list(df.index.values)
# print colNames
# print artists



for name in colNames:
    schedule_sheets = pd.ExcelFile(schedule[0]).sheet_names
    scheduleData = {}
    for s_sheet in schedule_sheets:
        scheduleData[s_sheet] = pd.read_excel(schedule[0],s_sheet, index_col='Time')
    finalSched = pd.concat(scheduleData).unstack(0)
    stages = list(finalSched.columns.values)
    indSched = finalSched.copy()
    asciiName = name.encode('ascii','ignore')
    for stage in stages:
        for dj in artists:
            for time,prevtime in zip(list(finalSched.index.values),list(finalSched.index.values)[1:]):
                if type(indSched.at[time,stage]) == float:
                    if math.isnan(indSched.at[time,stage]):
                        indSched.at[time,stage] = indSched.at[prevtime,stage]
                        finalSched.at[time,stage] = finalSched.at[prevtime,stage]
                if type(indSched.at[time,stage]) == str or type(indSched.at[time,stage]) == unicode:
                    if indSched.at[time,stage].lower() == dj.lower():
                        indSched.at[time,stage] = df.at[dj,name]
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(asciiName+'_schedule.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
    indSched.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=s_sheet)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[s_sheet]
    worksheet.conditional_format('B3:Y48',{'type': '3_color_scale'})
    writer.save()`
```

The above is my current code (I'm sure it is fairly inefficient but I'm just trying to get things to work currently).  I have tried doing the following to overwrite the data but it give me an excel error saying I need to repair the file before I can look at it.  It also removes the coloring.

```
indSched.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=s_sheet)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[s_sheet]
worksheet.conditional_format('B3:Y48',{'type': '3_color_scale'})
finalSched.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=s_sheet)
writer.save()
```

I'm a little stumped, and maybe this is the completely wrong way to go about things, but just wondering if anyone had some suggestions.

Here are the two files I am using to extract data from.  [One](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n324fha0hir0mo/edcLineup_Test.xlsx?dl=0) and [Two](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ud4be9id4ro8y2/edcSetTime_test.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Does it work without the conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes and no.  It fills in the spots with the names but I still get the error.   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>Repair Result to Aaron_schedule 03540.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'Macintosh HD:Users:AaronsMac:Documents:Aaron_schedule.xlsx'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>`

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the merged cells on that schedule. If you unmerge all cells on the source, does it work?

Comment: Unmerging all cells in all files did not fix the error.  However, I changed `finalSched.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=s_sheet)` to `finalSched.to_excel(writer)` and it now writes two separate sheets, one with colors and number and one with the Artists names.  But there is no error. So I feel the error is occurring when I try to "overwrite" the data with my second DataFrame.